# how to know to what pre-configured set of syntax tokens get expanded to?

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes, customization

in documentation of vscode there is a section [Editor syntax highlighting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_editor-syntax-highlighting)

> A pre-configured set of syntax tokens ('comments', 'strings', ...) is available for the most common constructs. I

what textmate grammer tokens these `comments` or `strings` sets cover?

I tried serching in vscode github source code repository, but I didn't understand a thing

Comment: what do you mean? Those are just standard token names for common/conventional language constructs. Exactly what patterns the token matches against depends on the language, as contributed by a language support extension, such as one of the [builtin lanugage support extensions in VS Code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions).